# SQL Server: how to insert the ' character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to insert some string with ' in it, for example 'x.y.x', After some research I discovered the following syntax:

```
table_b.element = 'replace('x.y.x','',''')'
```

the problem is that SQL Server gives me an error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ')

How can I solve this case? I spent about 2 hours on this.

Is there an escape character that I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write two single quotes:

```
replace('x.y.x','','''')
```

(This is true for all SQL databases)

Answer (score 0):

`'` is escaped with `''`, so if its a literal string within an SQL statement;

```
update t set fld = '''x.y.x'''
```

If your passing in a value to a procedure for example or your constructing a statement then using your client language you must `replace(data, "'", "''")` (or use prepared statements)

Comment: 'replace('x.y.z',"'","''")' gives me a Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Comment: Its unlear what you need? you would rarely need to use replace() **within** an sql statement to escape anything; if your passing/building a string containing ' then you need to escape it in your client language